# Excel formula by combining 2 sheets

Tags: excel, report

I need help in generating excel report.Can anyone of you please help me.

I have 2 excel files. I have tried to paste the files in the question.

#### file1:

```
Column A                    Column B        Column C
----------------------------------------------------
$www.example1.com/ab        200             abc
```

#### file 2:

```
URL                              Hits
-----------------------------------------
$www.something.com/dir/abc       1000
$www.example1.com/ab             100
$www.example2.com/cd             50
$www.example1.com/ab             100
```

1. Contains 3 columns -- colA (URLs), colB(Hits in Numerals), colC(some data)
2. Contains 2 columns -- ColA (URLs), ColB(Hits in Numericals)

Steps:

1. Take  ColA(URLs) from file1 and search in ColA(URL) of files2.
2. Suppose we get 10 searches, I need to get the Sum of all the ColB(Hits) of file2 and 
   place it in file1 ColB of the first result.

Any kind of hints would be helpful. I tried many options, but none of them worked.

Comment: Could it be the miss spelling of `$www.exapmle1.com/ab` in file 2?

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible under the following conditions:

- Both Files are open
- the URLs are the same

Then use code similar to this example:

`=SUMIF([Name of file 2]NameOfSheet!$A$2:$C$6;A2;[Name of file 2]NameOfSheet!$B$2:$B$6)`

Where `$A$2:$C$6` is the range of data in file 2 and `A2` is the cell with the value in file 1 and `$B$2:$B$6` is the range of data to be summed up within file 2.

Hope this helps.